# How To change Drop Down Option Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am Creating a Drop Down Button According to the Rank basis and option should be popped of when the existing Drop down has the same value (Rank)
and option should not be repeated.
Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LxLD.png)

[image]

If the rank number is range from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And if i select 1 from the drop down the number 1 should not be displayed on the drop down and if i remove 1 from the list it should back to the drop-down option

Note: i am using bootstrap and angular6.

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: please share code that is part of your research and developement.

Comment: @BogdanM. i have just created  dropdown Button but i have not coded yet but still you can see  <div class="dropdown" *ngFor = "let dropdownButton of dropDownOption">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              {{dropdownButton}}
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <span class="dropdown-item-text">Just Text</span>
              <span class="dropdown-item-text">Just Text</span>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: you can use filter method, onchange select

Comment: this.rank = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="my-style"  (change)="selectedOption($event)">
 <option selected disabled> Select option</option>
 <option *ngFor="let option of list; let i = index" >{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if you use select option, it works but you just need to bind a method as I did in above-written code 
AND
in your .ts file use method 

selectOption(event){
   console.log(event);
}

Answer (score 0):

There are two types form in angular. One is template driven and other is reactive form. In template driven you need to change the `ng-model value options` and in reactive form you can change the options using `FormControl name`